# Source stream outside scdf

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have read the documentation and it's not clear for me the following scenario:

the consumer is outside scdf and the processor and sink are inside.

All the examples provided, the three components are inside.

From my point of view I think that there are two solutions:

- The producer outside SCDF produces a message in the topic configured in SCDF
- There is another binder outside SCDF and the processor/sink connects to this binder outside SCDF

If somebody could provide any sample it will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your question what you mean by “outside scdf” . I assume you are referring to existing code that you want to use as a source for an scdf stream. It may already produce messages using a supported message middleware, for example it writes to a Kafka topic, or can be modified to do so but for some reason, you cannot use SCDF to manage its deployment. The simplest way to do this is to use the source topic as a named destination in your stream definition: `:my-topic > processor | sink`

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/named-destinations/

Comment: I will try to explain: the source is an application outside the spring cloud dataflow. It's not a spring boot application that will be deployed in scdf.

Comment: Named destination will work